# Pass parameter from Angular component to custom element

Tags: angular, lit-element

I am mergin an Angular app with an js (Lit element) app and I need to pass paramaters from the angular component to the custom element in the JS app.
I cannot seem to pass the actual value, but only the name of the variable I am trying to send. Any help?

```
@Input()
  public name: string = 'hurra';

<fund-view value=name></fund-view>
```

It comes out in the fund-view custom element attributes as I recieve it like this

```
 static get properties() {
    return {
      name: {
        type: String
      }
 }
```

This is what I get:
nodeValue: "name"

I even tried putting multiple brackets around the value, but then I receive absolute nothing.

How do I pass the actual value?

Answer (score 0):

To pass a property to a `lit-element` you need to use `.` before the property name.

Assuming `fund-view` is a `lit-element`, property assignment should look like this:

```js
<fund-view .someProperty="propertyValue"></fund-view>
```

Reference:
https://open-wc.org/guides/knowledge/attributes-and-properties/#templating

Comment: Thank you. But angular does not like the "dot" in front of the property name. We ended up with this <fund-view value={{name}}></fund-view>

Answer (score -1):

You need to write the property name in brackets as described in https://angular.io/guide/property-binding#binding-to-a-property

```
<fund-view [name]="name"></fund-view>
```

If your property is `name` it needs to be named `name` and not value.

Here is a codesandbox, that shows, that it works that way.
https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-lit-5b4t9f

Comment: A not useful answer without comment is rude.

Comment: Yes, Angular loves that. But Lit-element does not.

Comment: Here is an example. that it works exactly like I wrote in my answer. https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-lit-5b4t9f Lit does not care how a property is set, as long as it is set.